# Why don't list items line up on ul when using fontawesome fonts?

Tags: html, css

I have a list with font attached to it, but as you'll notice in the jsfiddle, the code doesn't line up:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lu1dLq92/1/ (now includes font-awesome external resource)

It seems like they line the list items relative to the bullets themselves instead of on a vertical line.

```
ul { list-style:none; }
li { margin-bottom:10px; }
li.calendar:before {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f073';
    margin:0 3% 0 -8%;
    color:#44b3d2;
}
```

Comment: You can try using [List Icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#list) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font-awesome icons have varying widths. As a result, when you set them to appear before your content, they will offset the starting position of that content by varying widths.

With font-awesome you can use their fixed width icons https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#fixed-width

Or a more generic solution is to set your `:before` tags to display as an inline block and then give them a consistent width.

```
li.calendar:before {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f073';
    margin:0 5px 0 -35px;
    color:#44b3d2;
}

li.map:before {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f041';
    margin:0 5px 0 -35px;
    color:#44b3d2;
}

li.map:before, li.calendar:before{
    display:inline-block;
    width:18px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lu1dLq92/3/